# Arch Linux - pacman -Syu failed - cannot issue any commands

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, glibc

I was running a full system update. Said update failed abruptly, with the last package modified seemingly being the removal of `glibc`. Now, nothing works. System built-ins such as `cd` still work, but on issuance of any other command, an error of the following form results:

```
bash: /usr/bin/COMMAND: No such file or directory
```

With some commands causing this error instead:

```
bash: /usr/bin/COMMAND: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I do not know how to proceed. I am scared to shut my computer down or to log out or to close my open terminals. I am using i3 and all keybindings for switching workspaces and the like still function normally, save for my bindings to open a new terminal or the like.

Is there a way for me to undo this package removal? Is that what caused this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented [on the pacman page of the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Pacman_crashes_during_an_upgrade):

> In the case that pacman crashes with a "database write" error while
>   removing packages, and reinstalling or upgrading packages fails
>   thereafter, do the following:
>
> 1. Boot using the Arch installation media. Preferably use a recent media
>      so that the pacman version matches/is newer than the system.
> 2. Mount the
>      system's root filesystem, e.g. mount `/dev/sdaX /mnt` as root, and check
>      the mount has sufficient space with `df -h`
> 3. Mount the proc, sys and dev
>      filesystems as well: `mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc; mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys; mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev`
> 4. If the system uses default
>      database and directory locations, you can now update the system's
>      pacman database and upgrade it via `pacman --sysroot /mnt -Syyu` as
>      root.
> 5. After the upgrade, one way to double-check for not upgraded but
>      still broken packages: `find /mnt/usr/lib -size 0`
> 6. Followed by a
>      re-install of any still broken package via `pacman --sysroot /mnt -S package`.

Comment: Solved. Thanks. For what it's worth, I had to run `pacman --root=/mnt` instead of `pacman --sysroot /mnt`. For some reason the option you recommended couldn't resolve the mirrors.